# Tests repeat with angular4 + mocha + karma

Tags: unit-testing, angular, karma-runner, karma-mocha

## Question/Issue

I've converted a basic project generated by angular-cli 1.0.0 from using jasmine to using mocha. **Why as I complete the conversion to mocha, do all the tests run twice?** Interestingly when we run the same tests/code with wallabyjs runner, or with a downgraded angular2, then the tests only run once.

To reproduce from scratch I took 3 steps with an optional 4th. Unfortunately there is a lot of code involved, so I've provided a repository to demonstrate and a command to follow along each step which can be found in the step detail.

### Step 1 create project with angular-cli

- `ng new someBlankProject`
- `cd someBlankProject`
- `ng test` expected result 3 tests run

#### Detail

- configuration

  - angular-cli + angular4 + karma + jasmine
- angular-cli project jasmine + karma test results

  - [only 3 tests in source](https://github.com/arranbartish/angular-cli-seed/tree/2bf12b577173085344a86e37726d9f7ece930c77)
- **command to reproduce**

  - `git clone git@github.com:arranbartish/angular-cli-seed.git 01-fresh-project; cd 01-fresh-project; git checkout 2bf12b577173085344a86e37726d9f7ece930c77;npm install;npm run test -- --single-run=true`

### Step 2 validate that jasmine tests run using karma and wallaby both locally and on CI

- introduce the [diff](https://github.com/arranbartish/angular-cli-seed/commit/0bb96884d0e71f286d0b4fedc0dcafd20dc9d2b1) to include CI and wallabyjs runner

  - `npm install` to resolve dependencies
- `ng test` expected result 3 tests run
- Confirm with wallabyjs `No failing tests, 3 passing`

#### Detail

- configuration

  - angular-cli + angular4 + karma + jasmine
- angular-cli project jasmine + karma test results

  - passing build [3 of 3 tests passing](https://travis-ci.org/arranbartish/angular-cli-seed/builds/222106899)
  - [only 3 tests in source](https://github.com/arranbartish/angular-cli-seed/tree/0bb96884d0e71f286d0b4fedc0dcafd20dc9d2b1)
- **command to reproduce**

  - `git clone git@github.com:arranbartish/angular-cli-seed.git 02-add-wallaby; cd 02-add-wallaby; git checkout 0bb96884d0e71f286d0b4fedc0dcafd20dc9d2b1;npm install;npm run test -- --single-run=true`
- wallabyjs result

  - `No failing tests, 3 passing`

### Step 3 introduce mocha and convert specs from jasmine to mocha

- introduce the [diff](https://github.com/arranbartish/angular-cli-seed/commit/0a9ed8804e15c451ff0d67ebd2d38980d54f9763) to convert to mocha

  - `npm prune;npm install` to clean and resolve dependencies
- `ng test` expected result **3 tests run** actual result **6 tests run**

  - `Chromeium 53.0.2785 (Ubuntu 0.0.0): Executed 6 of 3 SUCCESS (0.347 secs / 0.042 secs)`
- Confirm with wallabyjs `No failing tests, 3 passing`

#### Detail

- configuration

  - angular-cli + angular4 + karma + mocha
- angular-cli project mocha + karma test results

  - "Failed" build [6 of 3 tests passing](https://travis-ci.org/arranbartish/angular-cli-seed/builds/222107670)
  - [only 3 tests in source](https://github.com/arranbartish/angular-cli-seed/tree/0a9ed8804e15c451ff0d67ebd2d38980d54f9763)
- **command to reproduce**

  - `git clone git@github.com:arranbartish/angular-cli-seed.git 03-converted-mocha; cd 03-converted-mocha; git checkout 0a9ed8804e15c451ff0d67ebd2d38980d54f9763;npm install;npm run test -- --single-run=true`
- wallabyjs result

  - `No failing tests, 3 passing`

## Optional Observation

One of the strangest things that I've observed is that using angular 2 does not have the same behavior!

### Step 4 downgrade angular from 4 to 2

- introduce the [diff](https://github.com/arranbartish/angular-cli-seed/commit/0e6c2811b9aab722fcc382e4676d97c089ad1f91) to downgrade angular4

  - `npm prune;npm install` to clean and resolve dependencies
- `ng test` expected result 3 tests run
- Confirm with wallabyjs `No failing tests, 3 passing`

#### Step Detail

- configuration

  - angular-cli + angular2 + karma + mocha
- angular-cli project mocha + karma + angular2 test results

  - Passing build [3 of 3 tests passing](https://travis-ci.org/arranbartish/angular-cli-seed/builds/222125370)
  - [only 3 tests in source](https://github.com/arranbartish/angular-cli-seed/tree/0e6c2811b9aab722fcc382e4676d97c089ad1f91)
- **command to reproduce**

  - `git clone git@github.com:arranbartish/angular-cli-seed.git 04-downgrade-angular; cd 04-downgrade-angular; git checkout 0e6c2811b9aab722fcc382e4676d97c089ad1f91;npm install;npm run test -- --single-run=true`
- wallabyjs result

  - `No failing tests, 3 passing`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Frameworks configuration of karma is the issue

Because wallabyjs is working as expected, I've spent much of my time exploring karma and karma-mocha with a focus on the `karma.conf.js`

#### Broken karma.conf.js

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['mocha', 'chai', 'sinon-chai', '@angular/cli'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-mocha'),
      require('karma-chai'),
      require('karma-sinon'),
      require('karma-sinon-chai'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-phantomjs-launcher'),
      require('karma-mocha-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('karma-istanbul-threshold'),
      require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client:{
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    files: [
      { pattern: 'node_modules/sinon/pkg/sinon.js', instrument: false },
      { pattern: 'node_modules/chai/chai.js', instrument: false },
      { pattern: 'node_modules/sinon-chai/lib/sinon-chai.js', instrument: false },
      { pattern: './src/test.ts', watched: false }
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      './src/test.ts': ['@angular/cli']
    },
    mime: {
      'text/x-typescript': ['ts','tsx']
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly', 'json' ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    istanbulThresholdReporter: {
      src: 'coverage/coverage-final.json',
      reporters: ['text'],
      thresholds: {
        global: {
          statements: 95.01,
          branches: 75.59,
          lines: 91.89,
          functions: 89.23
        },
        each: {
          statements: 75.76,
          branches: 33.33,
          lines: 75,
          functions: 41.67
        }
      }
    },
    angularCli: {
      environment: 'dev'
    },
    reporters: config.angularCli && config.angularCli.codeCoverage
              ? ['progress', 'coverage-istanbul', 'istanbul-threshold']
              : ['progress', 'mocha'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

The approach I took was the best practice of just "try stuff until it works", which translates to me removing parts of the configuration line by line to see if it was important and to see if it changed the behavior.

## Resolution

Specifically the fix was removing `sinon-chai` and optionally `chai` from the `frameworks` array.

`frameworks: ['mocha', 'chai', 'sinon-chai', '@angular/cli'],`

becomes

`frameworks: ['mocha', '@angular/cli'],`

## Resources

The working code can be found at [this commit](https://github.com/arranbartish/angular-cli-seed/tree/44ae30320f2dadf9ade95e655da88bf30baebda1) with this [diff](https://github.com/arranbartish/angular-cli-seed/commit/44ae30320f2dadf9ade95e655da88bf30baebda1) using angular-cli / karma / mocha / angular4

### Travis build result

```
Chromium 53.0.2785 (Ubuntu 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 3 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
Chromium 53.0.2785 (Ubuntu 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 3 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.062 secs)
Chromium 53.0.2785 (Ubuntu 0.0.0): Executed 2 of 3 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.079 secs)
Chromium 53.0.2785 (Ubuntu 0.0.0): Executed 3 of 3 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.086 secs)
Chromium 53.0.2785 (Ubuntu 0.0.0): Executed 3 of 3 SUCCESS (0.32 secs / 0.086 secs)
```